# Debugger is not picking up the changes from visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, razor, knockout.js

I am trying to debug a project using the Chrome browser and even though I commented out some statements in visual studio, still the browser is showing the statements.

The lines commented:

[image]

Debugger window

[image]
I tried to clear the cache in the  chrome browser and tried to build and debug again but the browser is not picking up the changes. Can anyone please help me what could be the issue.

[image]

Comment: Is it happening for 1 form or all the forms? There might be many reasons for this to happen.

Comment: @VimalPatel Yes it is happening in  All the forms

Comment: Are you running the project using in build visual studio IIS Express?

Comment: @VimalPatel Yes I added the screenshot of the setting I am using

Comment: @VimalPatel I did try to delete the content of the debug folder and build and tried again to debug still no luck

Comment: Then it should work, to solve this we need your complete code.

Comment: @Vimal I have a huge project